# Newly created user role not displaying on users screen

Tags: wp-admin, users, admin, user-roles

I have created a new role with the following code:

```
add_role('sponsored_content', 'Sponsored Content', get_role('contributor')->capabilities);
```

I have added users to this role.
When viewing the users screen this **Sponsored Content** role does not display.
[image: Users screen not displaying the custom sponsored content role]

Using the browser inspect tool the markup is present:

```
<li class="sponsored_content"><a href="users.php?role=sponsored_content">Sponsored Content <span class="count">(6)</span></a> |</li>
```

There is styling coming from a "constructed stylesheet" preventing it from displaying:

```
.sponsored_content {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This is not styling that I have added and I do not know where it is coming from. Any ideas where this styling is coming from or how to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructed stylesheet was coming from the browser, in this case Brave Browser. The ad blocking feature added this styling. Turning shields off fixed the issue.